# Will moving domain name to new host affect subdomains?

Tags: domain, web-hosting, subdomain

I have one main domain name (www.myname.com) and I'm thinking of moving that to a new web host.

At the same host, I also have two subdomains (www.mycharity.org and www.mybook.com).

If I changes hosts for the main domain name, how will that affect the subdomains?

Comment: Those ain't subdomain they are domains, are you saying that you have your main domain myname.com with 2 extra domain alias that are mycharity.org and mybook.com ? at any rate they will stay working on the old host until the account is canceled.

Answer (score 1):

www is a subdomain of myname.com

www.charity.org is not a subdomain of myname.org it is a subdomain of charity.org.... which is a subdomain of the TLD .org....

ETC. for mybook.com

Regardless you should brush up on what a subdomain is.... There is a good meta on it on Serverfault somewhere... or Wikipedia is always good :)

And the answer to your question is no it will not effect your other domains as long as you continue to cover their costs with the hosting company.

Comment: Ah, ok - thanks @Prix and @Campo.  Off to brush up on terminology of subdomains. ;)

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark correct if we are going to close this question with my answer. A +1 is always nice too if it was helpful. If you require more clarification or wish to modify your question do so in an edit and I will reply with a answer :) You may need more rep before you can do so. But if you modify your question and it is useful and clear many will give you +1 and then you can do the same to those who helped you :)